# requirejs dependency function's this is window

Tags: javascript, requirejs

i use requirejs
and one dependency is

```
define(function(){
     .....
   fusionchart = function(){
       this.xxxx = ....;//the statement catch wrong,this is window not the object
  }
   return fusionchart;
});
```

i'm new to requirejs,i don't know why,and how to avoid it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with require here. "this" in inner functions always points to window.

Read http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/08/30/understanding-javascripts-this/

If fusionchart was meant to be a constructor function then:

```
define(function(){
    var FusionChart = function(){
       this.x = 0;
    };
    return FusionChart;
});
```

elsewhere in your code:

```
define(function(){
    var FusionChart = require('FusionChart');
    var fusionChartInstance = new FusionChart();
});
```

You can make FusionChart behave as a singleton by returning new FusionChart(); Then you won't have to create an instance when you require it. Requirejs will always point to the same reference.

```
define(function(){
    var FusionChart = function(){
       this.x = 0;
    };
    return new FusionChart();
});

define(function(){
    var fusionChartInstance = require('FusionChart');
});
```

Comment: thanks,and i change to use shim,like requirejs.config({shim:{'fusionCharts':{exports:'FusionCharts'}}}); and FusionCharts.js is  notAMD compatible (not have define before),but this still is window

Comment: Do you create a new instance of FusionCharts?